# undefined method 'do' within a rails controller.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble writing my `edit` method in a simple rails app.  I keep getting an error stating, `undefined method 'do'` in my `update` method.

I actually have two questions with this.  First off, I'm not sure what the error is, or how to fix it.  My second question is i've run into errors like this before, yet i've always struggled with solving them.  Is there any helpful advice on solving these kind of errors?

Here is my `controller`, and my `show` page. I don't think anything else is needed, but will bring it if needed.

```
%h1= @item.title
%h3= @item.description

= link_to "Home", root_path
= link_to "Edit", edit_item_path(@item)
= link_to "Delete", item_path(@item), method: :delete, data: {confirm:     "Are you sure?"}
```

My controller (I condensed this part)

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def edit
 end

 def update
  if @item.do(items_params)
    redirect_to @item
  else
    render "Edit"
  end
 end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

`do` is not an `ActiveRecord` method. It looks like you want `@item.update`. To avoid problems like this in the future, read [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#update) and [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update).